# What's the right version of Angular to use that supports ngRx/data?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I'm trying to build a project (https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2021/07/ngrx-v12-an-angular-state-management-using-ngrx-data.html) that uses ngRx/data.  I have the following version of Angular installed

```
$ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.2.19
Node: 14.15.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.19
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.19
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.19
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.19
@angular/cli                    11.2.19
@schematics/angular             11.2.19
@schematics/update              0.1102.19
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.1.6
```

My angular.json file is as follows

```
$ cat angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ngrx-data-example": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ngrx-data-example",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngrx-data-example:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ngrx-data-example:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ngrx-data-example:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ngrx-data-example:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ngrx-data-example:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ngrx-data-example"
}
```

I have repeatedly removed my node_modules and package-lock.json files, but after running

```
npm i
```

and then

```
ng serve
```

I keep getting the errors

```
Error: node_modules/@ngrx/data/src/actions/entity-action-factory.d.ts:36:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/ngrx-data-example/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

36     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<EntityActionFactory, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@ngrx/data/src/actions/entity-action-factory.d.ts:37:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/ngrx-data-example/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

37     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<EntityActionFactory>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

...
Error: ./node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2015/ngrx-store.mjs 180:29-44
Can't import the named export 'BehaviorSubject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2015/ngrx-store.mjs 361:29-44
Can't import the named export 'BehaviorSubject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2015/ngrx-store.mjs 456:20-35
Can't import the named export 'BehaviorSubject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

...
```

What is the appropriate version of Angular I should be using to support ngrx/data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep both versions the same.

If you're using angular 11, you should use ngrx 11.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited my package.json to change the versions of the ngrx packages to 11.1.1 and everything compiled and built.